# Delete key from redis

Tags: redis

I set the following with redis:

```
var db = require("redis");
var dbclient = db.createClient();
dbclient.hmset("file:"+key,"size", size);
```

I want to delete the `"file:"+key` record, but I do not find a way to do that. I just find a way to delete the `"size"` record, no the `"file"+key` record (with [hdel](http://redis.io/commands/hdel)).

Comment: From your 50 questions asked on this site, you've accepted only 5. The way this site works is, when you receive an answer that solves your question, you accept it by clicking the check mark right next to it on the left. That way you will help future readers to find the answer they were looking for, and you as well as the answerer will gain some reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `del` to delete a key:

```
dbclient.del("file:" + key, function(ok){
    console.log(ok);
});
```